# find difference between current and last revision in azure devops repo giving error

Tags: git, github, azure-devops

I am running a scan script, which will scan the incremental changes on all the files pushed/changed. While running the git command **git diff --name-only HEAD~** gives me the desired result, but in some repositories, it's not working and throwing an error as below.

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Any help would be really appreciated, if someone can point where I am going wrong here.

Comment: If a repo has only *one* commit, there's no `HEAD~` to be found.

Comment: all the repositories are having multiple commits

Comment: Are you doing a shallow clone and working on it?

Comment: Yes its working on shallow clone as well

Comment: that explains it... git only has the last commit from that branch in the local repo... you need to bring at least the previous commit so that comparing with the previous commit can be done.

Comment: So.... @RomainValeri's comment was right on target... only needed more information to have the full context.

Comment: Yes, issue is with commit, where there is only one commit and it's not able to commit. But the pipeline has default check out in azure devops, where for some repo its fetching complete history and for some its fetching only one commit which is the latest one. Any idea anyway to bypass this?

Answer (score 0):

As **`@RomainValeri`** and **`@eftshift0`** suggested above, you should ensure that you have cloned multiple commits to the local repository from the remote repository, and the cloned commits contains the ones you want to compare.

- Use the **`--depth`** option on the **`git clone`** command to clone the specified number of last commits that contains all the commits you want to compare. The **`{depthNumber}`** should greater than **`1`**.

  ```bash
  git clone --branch $(Build.SourceBranchName) --depth {depthNumber} {RepoURL}
  ```
- Or omit the **`--depth`** option on the **`git clone`** command to directly clone the full commits from the remote repository.

  ```bash
  git clone --branch $(Build.SourceBranchName) {RepoURL}
  ```

Comment: Yes, issue is with commit, where there is only one commit and it's not able to commit. But the pipeline has default check out in azure devops, where for some repo its fetching complete history and for some its fetching only one commit which is the latest one. Any idea anyway to bypass this?

Comment: @Devops-Learner, you can use "**`- checkout: none`**" to disable the default checkout task in the pipeline. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout?view=azure-pipelines#examples